# Fragment inflation from different flavors

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-flavors

I am learning Android and I cannot find the solution to a fragment instantiation error when they are in different flavors.

Setup:

- I have a main fragment that is loaded into the main activity.
- I have two favors: paid and free.
- The main (common) part of the app doesn't have the fragment (layout + java files), I put them into the favors.

I get the following error when I try to run my program:

```
01-24 19:38:06.211 27417-27417/com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid, PID: 27417
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid/com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:499)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3637)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have tried many different versions of the fragment name because the error message tells me that the problem is with that, unfortunately none of them worked. Could you please help me to find the route cause of the issue (I mean not just the solution but why doesn't this work)? [The code can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/judit-juhasz/flavour-sandbox), but the relevant files are here:

**src/java/com/udacity/gradle/builditbigger/MainActivity.java**

```
package com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void tellJoke(View view) {
    new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(this);
}
}
```

**src/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

**src/free/java/com/udacity/gradle/builditbigger/free/MainActivityFragment.java**

```
package com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.R;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return root;
}
}
```

**src/free/res/layout/fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/instructions_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instructions" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/instructions_text_view"
    android:onClick="tellJoke"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**src/paid/java/com/udacity/gradle/builditbigger/paid/MainActivityFragment.java**

```
package com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.R;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return root;
}
}
```

**src/paid/res/layout/fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/instructions_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instructions" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/instructions_text_view"
    android:onClick="tellJoke"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile, I found the solution. In `src/res/layout/activity_main.xml` you need to give the `android:name` attribute to the fragment in order to make it work. The name is the same in both flavors (`MainActivityFragment`), but the namespaces are different (`free` and `paid`). The only way to resolve this issue is that you need to move this layout file to the flavor parts of the application, and delete the original from the main part. Long story short, you have to delete the `src/res/layout/activity_main.xml` file, and add these two files to the project:

**src/free/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free.MainActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

**src/paid/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid.MainActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

I am sorry for the original question, but I hope that it will be useful for someone.